# Implement ExpandableListView in Navigation Drawer generated by android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer with a collapsable list view in my app. I want it to appear as follows:

[image: screenshot]

But I get this result:

[image: screenshot]

The Nav drawer is generated by android studio "Drawer Activity" template and here is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void enableExpandableList() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    prepareListData(listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    listAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            // till here
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void prepareListData(List<String> listDataHeader, Map<String,
            List<String>> listDataChild) {


    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Product1");
    listDataHeader.add("product2");
    listDataHeader.add("Product3");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top = new ArrayList<String>();
    top.add("x1");
    top.add("x2");
    top.add("x3");
    top.add("x4");
    top.add("x5");


    List<String> mid = new ArrayList<String>();
    mid.add("y1");
    mid.add("y2");
    mid.add("y3");

    List<String> bottom = new ArrayList<String>();
    bottom.add("z1");
    bottom.add("z2");
    bottom.add("z3");



    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), mid);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), bottom);
}
```

ExpandListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                         HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dcs.wallhouse.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a LinearLayout so they views won't overlap. The problem is you won't have a single scrolling area.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

       <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your app_bar_main.xml layout?

Comment: I think I just understood what is wrong - you have two lists, one on top of the other. The NavigationView menu & the left_drawer ExpandableListView. As NavigationView is a FrameLayout its child ExpandableListView is on top of it.

Comment: I updated the code - however, since you probably want a single scrolling area, perhaps you should put all the items inside the ExpandableListView.

Comment: I added the layout to the OP. Unluckly now with your updated code the app crashes with this error: "IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT" which I wan't able to fix. How can I statically add the elements to the ExpandableListView?

Comment: I was able to translate down the E.ListView by adding a paddingTop of 250dp, but it's not perfect and I would like to have it aligned with the other two static options

Comment: Added the android:layout_gravity="start" - it should solve the crash.

Comment: Sorry to bother but now its not displayng anything - there should appear a recycler view: http://i.imgur.com/rnRNl5T.png ---- Expcted view: http://i.imgur.com/2WSXxeY.jpg

Comment: Is this related? If not, you should open another question.

Comment: Well yes, I added android:layout_gravity="start" to the code you provided and the balnk screen happens. I still can't get the expandable list to work.